# How to find the number of homomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the maps $\mu:\mathbb{Z}→\mathbb{Z}$ and  $\mu:\mathbb{Z}→\mathbb{Z}_2$. For example if I am asked to find the number of homomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z}$, and of $\mathbb{Z}$ onto $\mathbb{Z}_2$, what do I  have to do? I don't have idea here. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of homomorphisms? Group homomorphisms and ring homomorphisms, for example, satisfy different conditions, so there are maps that are one but not the other.

Comment: @Junior: Presumably you meant $\mathbb{Z}_2$, not $\mathbb{Z}^2$, since you used the word "onto". Am I correct?

Comment: A homomorphism $\mu: \mathbb{Z} \to G$ (where $G$ is a group) is uniquely determined by $\mu(1)$ (can you see why?).

Comment: @Henning Makholm:group homomorphisms

Comment: @Zev:yes correct

Comment: @Pedro:i don't know why

Comment: @JuniorII To see Pedro's Remark: Note that any element in a group can be written in terms of its generators. Now, since the group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ is a cyclic ( and hence abelian) group and it has only on generator, you must be able to write any element as finite "sum" of its generator $1$. This together with $\mu$ being a homomorphism should prove his remark.

Answer (score 2):

A group homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\to R$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ to any commutative ring $R$ is determined by the image of $1$ since $f(n)=n f(1)$. If $f$ is required to be a ring homomorphism, we know $f(1)=1$, so there is only one homomorphism at all. This property means that $\mathbb{Z}$ is the *"initial object"* in the category of rings.

Comment: Dear rattle: I think that $$\sum_{i=1}^{-1}\ f(1)$$ is equal to $0$, not to $-f(1)$.

Comment: what to do if it is a group homomorphism?

Comment: @Pierre-Yves : I believe somehow rattle meant $nf(1)$ but just didn't state his point right.

Comment: Dear @PatrickDaSilva: Thanks for your comment! It looks quite convincing to me.

Comment: You guys were right of course. Sorry for the confusion there. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

This question isn't very well-posed, but luckily there's a general answer to your question. The following identities are easily verified

1) $$\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$$

2) When $n\geqslant2$ $$\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_n)\cong\mathbb{Z}_n$$

3) When $n\geqslant 2$ $$\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z})\cong0$$

4) When $n,m\geqslant2$  $$\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m)\cong\mathbb{Z}_{(n,m)}$$

With this all in mind, and using the fact that $\text{Hom}$ and $\oplus$ (for finitely many groups) commute in both variables one can deduce that

$$\text{Hom}\left(\mathbb{Z}^r\times\mathbb{Z}_{\ell_1}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}_{\ell_n},\mathbb{Z}^s\times\mathbb{Z}_{k_1}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}_{k_m}\right)\cong\mathbb{Z}^{rs}\times\prod_{j=1}^{m}\mathbb{Z}_{k_j}^m\times\prod_{i=1}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^m\mathbb{Z}_{(\ell_i,k_j)}$$

Of course, this gives you a theoretical way to find the Hom group between any two finitely generated abelian groups, as well.